# Why Visual Studio makes duplicates of .dlls in build folder?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

[image]
I work on the project that I have inherited from another developer. It is mix of VB.NET & C#. 
Solution is made of multiple projects: `Config`(start-up project),`Common`,`Agent` + project `StdPlugin` under `Plugin` folder. (Plugins are .dlls that are loaded during runtime). 
For non-plugin projects, output path is set to `bin\Debug\`. For Plugins projects output path is set to `Config\bin\Debug\Plugins`.

After the project is compiled, `Config\bin\Debug\` has all `.dll`s +`.pdb`s and `.exe` for all my projects. However, `Config\bin\Debug\Plugins` also contains copies of all project `.dll`s + `.pdb`s and `.ddl` + `.pdb` for `StdPlugin` project. In other words, I am getting duplicates. On top of that, when I run `Build->Clean Solution`, `Config\bin\Debug\` is being cleaned out, but `Config\bin\Debug\Plugins` is not.

**Some clarifications:** **1.** Project is build for debugging. **2.** I noticed above issues while investigating  `The source file is different from the module was build` issue that affects the `Reader` project. It would not stop on breakpoins in `Reader` project.

Comment: Do the plugins have references to the other projects or binaries? if so is "copy local" set to true on those references? If that's the case then MSbuild will copy them to the output folder. You should also see if any post build steps have been set up to copy the binaries in to the 'debug\plugins' directory

Comment: @JamesReed `StandardPlugins` references `Agent`&`Reader`&`Common` projects (and I guess they might reference other projects as well). 
References for those thee projects are set to `Copy Local = True`. Pre/Post-Build events are blank.

Comment: @JamesReed Just ran it with `Copy Local = False` and outputs only one `.dll` - StandardPlugins module, along with it's `.pdb`. So I guess, I have to sit down and and figure out how to write Post-build event to copy the files

Comment: If you want those binaries in your plugins directory then you should have copy local set to 'true' if you're getting stale binaries, i.e. 'the source file is different' then it's probably a problem with the way the files are being referenced. Are they project references or binary references to the 'debug\bin' directory? If they are binary references then the problem is being caused because MSBuild cannot determine the correct build order and your plugins are being built before their dependencies. You could try removing the references completely and adding them again as project references

Comment: @JamesReed. I have no idea, but your suggestion worked and helped me fix the `the source file is different` error. 
I have re-created the `Reader` project from the scratch, compiled solution, it gave me `BadImageFormatException`, changed `Target CPU` to `AnyCPU` and it worked. 
As for my original question, I have resorted to temporary measure. `StandardPlugins` will compile to `Config\bin\Debug\Plugins` folder. Later on, I will set-write Post-Build event command.
I will gladly accept you first response as answer.