# Duplication of dll files while publishing web site in VS 2013 nop framework

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nopcommerce

I have developed web application on nopCommerce framework and when i publish that web site it creates duplicate dll files in bin and plugins folder. which increases size of build.

Earlier this not use to happen. how can i avoid duplication of dll files in publish folder.

Comment: delete old files and try to build.

Comment: i have already set publish settings to delete and create publish.

Comment: i am unable to understand why Visual studio duplicating dll files. earlier dll files was present only in bin folder inside publish folder. Now it is creating new set of dll files in my plugins folder, which are already there in bin folder. which is increasing build size "size of publish folder".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648736/why-visual-studio-makes-duplicates-of-dlls-in-build-folder check this out

Answer (score 0):

plug-in folder you need to copy only your assembly dll. foreign assembly dll to be removed. You can also check out the [official documentation of the development of plugins](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/How+to+write+a+nopCommerce+plugin).